# Edit message with interval

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have code that should edit a discord message per each execution. Everything seems to be work fine, but when I add interval functionality(to execute it code every minute) it couldn't edit bot message anymore:

call:

```
setInterval(function () { var data = getData(response, list); editMessage(data) }, 60000)
```

function with message edit

```
function editMessage(data) {
    client.on('ready', () => {
        client.guilds.cache.get('server').channels.cache.get('channel').messages.fetch('message').then(message => {
            message.edit('new message content');
        }).catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
        });;
    });
}
```

So I can receive the `data` inside `editMessage` function, but anything that goes inside of `client.on('ready', () => {...` can't be engaged with interval function. What could be the case?

I'm using Discord.js 12 version.

Comment: Bad idea. Making an API call every minute is API abuse and will lead your account being suspended from using it

Comment: it will be adjusted later. Its my API so no one going to suspend for extra requests.

Comment: If you're editing a *Discord* message it's *Discord*'s API. `<Message>.edit()` makes a POST request each time

Comment: Ah, thought you were saying about ```response```. No problem, it will be edited as things will be sorted out. Thanks for heads up though.

Comment: ALso https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, I made this work in a different approach. I've wrapped the [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) function inside of [`client.on`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/Client?scrollTo=e-ready) and it works as intended.

```
        client.on('ready', () => {
            client.guilds.cache.get('server').channels.cache.get('channel').messages.fetch('message').then(message => {
                setInterval(function () {
                message.edit('new message content');
                console.log('new message content')
            }, 1 * 30000);
            }).catch(err => {
                console.error(err);
            });;
        });
```